# How to match exact string in a list using Python

Tags: python, string, list, search

I want to search exactly if a string is in a command list. If yes, then append it to a match list. However, it doesn't give me the desire result.

```
cmd_list = ["passwd", "/etc/passwd"]
string = "[cat /etc/passwd | grep finftp]"

matches = []

for word in sorted(cmd_list):
    if word in string:
       matches.append(word)      
print(matches)
```

The expected output should be ONLY "/etc/passwd". But it shows this output here:
['/etc/passwd', 'passwd']. I know another way of doing it like just give it a condition, but it is not an ideal solution as I got a lot of command list and all of them maybe dynamic.

Comment: Did any of the given answers solve your problem? If so, would you consider upvoting and accepting it?

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string into words and then check if any of the words match your commands. Here's how you can do it:

```
cmd_list = ["passwd", "/etc/passwd"]
string = "[cat /etc/passwd | grep finftp]"   
matches = [word for word in cmd_list if word in string.split()]   
print(matches)
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but may also be shortened to just: `matches = [word for word in cmd_list if word in string.split()]`

Comment: @DamianSatterthwaite-Phillips While this is shorter in code, it will be less efficient, as `string.split()` will be called for each `word` (i.e. for each element in `cmd_list`) in your version, whereas it will be called only once in the version from the answer.

Comment: Now that the original answer has been edited, my comment does not make sense, any more. For the record: Originally, the `split()` had been done outside the list comprehension and its result stored in its own variable. Which still make more sense to me than the current version: Why would you want to apply `split()` in each iteration for the sake of saving one line of code?

Comment: To clarify: the answer given by @Aswin above, was edited to incorporate my (unedited) suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that you're using the `in` operator, which checks if a substring exists in the given string. In your case, both "passwd" and "/etc/passwd" are present as substrings in the input string "[cat /etc/passwd | grep finftp]". This is why both "passwd" and "/etc/passwd" are being added to the `matches` list.

If you want to search for exact matches from your `cmd_list`, you can modify your code to compare each word in the `cmd_list` against the whole string, rather than using the `in` operator:

```py
cmd_list = ["passwd", "/etc/passwd"]
string = "[cat /etc/passwd | grep finftp]"

matches = []

for word in sorted(cmd_list):
    if word == string.strip("[]"):
        matches.append(word)
        
print(matches)
```

In this code, `string.strip("[]")` is used to remove the square brackets from the input string before comparing it with each word in the `cmd_list`. This will ensure that you get the exact match you're looking for. The expected output will be `['/etc/passwd']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by spaces (or also possibly brackets, if you want to be able to match `cat`, not `[cat`), then use `in` on the resultant array.

```
import re

cmd_list = ["passwd", "/etc/passwd"]
string = "[cat /etc/passwd | grep finftp]"
split_string = re.split('[ \[\]]', string)

matches = []

for word in sorted(cmd_list):
    if word in split_string:
       matches.append(word)      
print(matches)
```

Also, off-topic, and probably a matter of personal style, but I would be more likely to write the second part as a comprehension:

```
matches = [word for word in sorted(cmd_list) if word in split_string]
```